# NLinesInputFormat Alternative in Hadoop 0.20?

Tags: hadoop

I am working with Hadoop 0.20, and wish to use the NLinesInputFormat, but this functionality isn't present?

Is there an alternative?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Records in the data span multiple lines, so I shall set NLinesInputFormat to a multiple of 'k', where k is the number of lines each record takes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[NLineInputFormat](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.0/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/NLineInputFormat.java) (it's Line and not Lines) is there in 0.20. New MR API was introduced in 0.20, but NLineInputFormat was not ported to the new API.

If you are using the new MR API, then you can try porting new API NLineInputFormat from some other release into 0.20. It shouldn't be that difficult and you would also be learning how to compile and build a Hadoop jar.